# Kivy center button

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a simple test app in Kivy for learning:

```
class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

class PhoneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PhoneApp().run()
```

This my .kv:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
<Label>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<Image>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<Button>
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<GridLayout>
    cols: 1
    size_hint: (0.5, 0.9)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

<MyWidget>:
    Image:
        source: "captus.png"
    
    Label:
        text: "Test Message"        

    Button:
        text: "Second test"
```

The problem is that the button isn't aligned, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

The green button "Second test" should be centered, in the middle of the window, like "Test Message" is.

I've been playing with `pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}` but I can't manage to center that button...

How can I center the "Second test" button?

Comment: try ```pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}```, tell me if that works

Comment: didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a `GridLayout` does not honor `pos_hint` at all. So getting a widget centered in a `GridLayout` cell takes a bit of planning.

One way is to just make the `Button` fill the width of the `GridLayout` cell. That doesn't actually center the `Button`, but the text of the `Button` will be centered. To so this, just remove the `size_hint_x: None` line from the `<Button>:` rule in your `kv`.

Another way is to put the `Button` in a container that fills the `GridLayout` cell, and center the `Button` in that container. An `AnchorLayout` serves just that purpose. Try replacing the `Button` part of your `<MyWidget>:` rule with:

```
AnchorLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: butt.height  # same height as the Button
    Button:
        id: butt
        text: "Second test"
```

A third option is to not use `GridLayout`. If you are only using 1 column or 1 row, a `BoxLayout` may be a better approach. And a `BoxLayout` supports `pos_hints` (partially, see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html)). To use this approach, change `MyWidget` to extend `BoxLayout`:

```
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Then you can use the `pos_hint` as suggested by @mohammad-alqashqish in the `kv`:

```
<Label>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<Image>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<Button>
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<GridLayout>
    cols: 1
    size_hint: (0.5, 0.9)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        source: "tester.png"
    
    Label:
        text: "Test Message"  

    Button:
        text: "Second test"   
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
```

One other thing to note. When you make a rule in `kv` for a standard widget, like `<Label>:`, that rule will be applied to every `Label` you create in your app after that `kv` is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, this helps too much and I appreciate this <3 Btw... "When you make a rule in kv for a standard widget, like <Label>:, that rule will be applied to every Label you create in your app after that kv is loaded." that is on purpose I want to affect all labels. Thanks <3